Dongle Support for 16 bit Program with Win 11 using WineVDM
I need to run an old 16-bit database (related to an instrument) in a new 64bit Win11 pc. As ntvdm is no longer included in newer version of Win10 and Win11, I installed this program with the open source version "otvdm".
The software runs perfectly.
The problem is that it is protected by SafeNet Sentinel dongles (either usb or parallel).
The 16 bit program does not "see" the dongles...
I suppose that the driver used, that obviously is a 64 bit version of the Sentinel driver, could not be visible to my 16bit software as it is emulated through otvdm.
I was wondering if it could be possible to give instruction to otvdm to use a particular dll or driver that finally could let my software work with the dongle...

This doesn't seem like a retro related question, but reated modern software and its interaction and quirks, i.e. Win 10/11 and OTVDM. The later being in active development, so best might be to ask right there (maybe check for issues or create one) and/or look at the various sites around WINE (WINEHQ's help pages might be a good start), as OTVDM is essentially WINE as Windows VDM.

(P.S.: Adding detailed information/links about software used and configuration to future questions could be helpful to speed up any answer.)

While emulation questions are probably off-topic, I think this question is on-topic as a [tag:new-hardware-adaptation] question (getting the adapter and software to talk to each other via the new computer). As a practical matter, it might be easier to crack the software: such a question would be within the site's scope, except that people might want to close it as piracy-related.

@wizzwizz4  To me this is not about old software nor about modifying it, but requesting a certain functionality from a modern (non-)emulator software. It seems to be clearly about how low level USB or Parallel access is forwarded by it (Nonetheless, I tried to give as many hints as possible where to continue to search). Also, I have no problem with RC.SE covering investigation of workings of older software (even if derogatory (in general, not referring specific to your use) called cracking or piracy, which IMHO it nether is). It might, in fact, be a very fine topic for us.

The crazy thing is that if the question were rephrased to avoid mentioning WineVDM, it would probably be on-topic under “how to use or preserve computing equipment that is no longer manufactured or supported by the manufacturer”, and answers to that using WineVDM would look similar to possible answers to this question as it currently stands... Do we want to punish users who try to do things themselves before asking for help?

@StephenKitt good point. But the issue isn't that he found a way to use his old software, but asks for a service to a modern product. I would expect anyone to first ask at that products github site or at the main site for it's base (wine) and only to come here if neither of those were able to help. This would not make it more on topic to me, but show that he has exhausted reasonable search for a solution on his own -  as requested for any question by default (aka missing research). In a situation like this RC.Se in that case working as last resort - which I think is fine.

@StephenKitt And yes, it is quite often depends on the angle under wich a problem is seen to make it on- or off-topic. Same way as I'll be quite willing to spend my time to help some random person recover their old love letters from an 8" disks, while doing the same for a company will need a written order and attached cheque.

@Raffzahn I understand what the issue is; my point is just that if mentions of WineVDM were removed from the question, it would be on-topic, and someone might well answer with detailed instructions on how to configure WineVDM to get the dongle to work ;-). I agree that it would probably be more productive (as in, the OP would be more likely to get an accurate answer) to ask the project maintainers directly.

How much interaction does your application need with Windows 11? Would running 32-bit Windows XP, 7, 8 or 10 in a VirtualBox VM with USB passthrough be an alternative?

Welcome to SE/RC! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and you might want to read some pages of the [help], too. Then come back and [edit] your question to add if this software is a Windows program or a DOS program, please.

Very partial answer: Looking at otvdm.ini, there are several ways to do the emulation (VM dll, hypervisor haxmvm.dll, gvm.dll, whpxvm.dll), so the first thing to do is to edit your question and indicate which one you use, the second is to try out the other variants, the third is to go through all variants and see if you can configure parallel port or USB in any way to get at your dongle. .
Third point requires to understand how otvdm calls those things (or to bypass otvdm and run those directly), to see where the configuration files are.
The fourth is to try and fine a Wine configuration file, as otvdm seems to be based on Wine.
